# Odoo installed using Docker Compose on AWS generates an error: ERROR ? werkzeug: code 400, message Bad request version ('jj\x13

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, backend, odoo, devops

I installed Odoo 14 Community on AWS EC2 using a docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  web:
    image: odoo:14.0
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8069:8069"
  db:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo
      - POSTGRES_USER=odoo
```

When I connect to this instance I get an error in the browser:

> This site can’t provide a secure connection
> sent an invalid response.
>
> Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
>
> ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

And in the terminal I can see the error in the log:

> INFO ? odoo.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on
> d2611a313581:8069 web_1  | 2022-03-11 15:12:40,859 1 ERROR ? werkzeug:
> 156.210.29.121 - - [11/Mar/2022 15:12:40] code 400, message Bad request version ('>Ë»æúº\x95¼\x83\x9d\x90\x0fÎönh\x05¥R\x01ÎãüZX¥Ê') -

The security group is configured to accept connections:

[image]

I used to make the exact same configuration and it worked before.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured it out.

The browser adds `https://` automatically before the IP - while it should be `http://` because I didn't use any security with the built-in Odoo webserver.

Just removed the letter `s` and it worked.